# Xampp control panel apache error

Tags: php, xampp

```
I installed xampp control panel v3.2.1  , my apache is not working as it gives error that 


12:43:58  [Apache]  Problem detected!
12:43:58  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
12:43:58  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
12:43:58  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
12:43:58  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

i dont have anything running on my background . any alternative ??

Comment: netstat -an What's running on port 80?

Answer (score 2):

Your system port 80 used by other resources. That's the reason for this error.
Change default port 80 into something

Goto your xampp folder > apache >config> find httpd file. On that file  Search word listen.  Default it set as 80 change into 2000 or 3000 any.  Save that file. Run again your xampp.  :)

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you have Skype running. If that's your case and you don't want to change your Apache configuration, open Skype and look for the menu Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection. Uncheck the box "Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections"